# How to Create or Drawing Separator/Divider Line with text in Layout android?

Tags: java, android, drawing, line, separator

How to create a line with text in android in layout.
Like

```
--------------------OR----------------
```

Comment: Why don't you just copy the above to a TextView?

Comment: It's a overview but i want to use Separator in Layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.if you want to use **constraint layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <View
            android:id="@+id/first_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text"
            android:background="@color/white80"/>
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/first_divider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/first_divider"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first_divider"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second_divider"
            android:textColor="@color/white80"
            android:text="OR"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/second_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/white80"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2.if you want to use **LinearLayout**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/first_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/white80"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white80"
            android:text="OR"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/second_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white80"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

3.if you want using **relative layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/first_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/white80"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white80"
            android:text="OR"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/second_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
            android:background="@color/white80"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here the result** :

[image]

Comment: Yes I want same result but in linear layout.

Comment: I've edited my answer when using linear layout @UmeshYadav

Comment: Thank You. What can It also we do in Relative Layout.

Comment: It's possible to using relative layout too, check updated answer